# Create Dropdown menu in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, admin

I'm updating a plugin and I need to build a select.

I'm new in Magento2, and I found this idea: [Magento 2: How add dropdown in admin form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156864/magento-2-how-add-dropdown-in-admin-form/)

I'm building something similar but I'm not able to display it in Admin Panel.

here the function:

```
<?php
namespace Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Block\System\Config;

class SelectFattureCreaFattura extends 
\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field implements 
\Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
public function toOptionArray()
{
$result = [];

foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
    $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
}
return $result;
}

/**
* Retrieve option array
*
* @return string[]
*/
public static function getOptionArray()
{
return [
    [1 => __('Disabilitata')],
    [2 => __('Fattura NON Elettronica')],
    [3 => __('Fattura Elettronica')]
];

}

/**
* Retrieve option array with empty value
*
* @return string[]
*/
public function getAllOptions()
{
$result = [];

foreach (self::getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
    $result[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
}

 return $result;
}

/**
* Retrieve option text by option value
*
* @param string $optionId
* @return string
*/
public function getOptionText($optionId)
{
$options = self::getOptionArray();

return isset($options[$optionId]) ? $options[$optionId] : null;
}
}
```

I know I need a template but I don't know where to place it exactly and how to build it. Thanks to all David

Comment: "Something goes wrong" we can't work with this. give us more information.

Comment: I found this way: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158262/magento-2-dropdown-option-not-showing-in-admin-form

Actually I am still not able to display my dropdown in admin menu. I think it should be enough to put the model in the correct path, but I don't know where exactly.

Comment: Actually I'm not able to display the options in admin menu, and I think this is due to my template file and its path.

Comment: @Davide Iandoli Can you specify magento version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it creating CreaFattura.php file like this:

```
<?php

class Fattura24_AppFatturazione_Model_System_Config_Source_CreaFattura
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $option = array(
            array('value' => 'd', 'label' => 'Disabilitata'),
            array('value' => 'f', 'label' => 'Fattura NON Elettronica'),
            array('value' => 'fe', 'label' => 'Fattura Elettronica'),
        );

        return $option;
    }
}
```

then to display my options I added this snippet in system.xml

```
<crea_fattura translate="label comment">
                            <label>Crea fattura</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>appfatturazione/system_config_source_CreaFattura</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</crea_fattura>
```

in source_model there is the path in which I put class CreaFattura